# windows.location.href to pass a list of integers (List<int>) to an MVC action method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there was a way to use windows.location.href to pass a list of integers (List) to an MVC action method  It will let me pass one value if that value is hardcoded but thats not my need..

This works and passes to the action method fine:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportCSV", "Admin", new { FundraiserIDs = "15169" })';
```

This code here (with some random numbers put into a javascript array) tells the that FundraiserIDsadd "does not exist in the current context"

```
    var FundraiserIDsadd = [];
        FundraiserIDsadd.push(19336);
        FundraiserIDsadd.push(15169);
        FundraiserIDsadd.push(15176);    

window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportCSV", "Admin", new { FundraiserIDs = FundraiserIDsadd })';
```

And here is my controller action method:

```
public ActionResult ExportCSV(List<int> FundraiserIDs)
    {
        DO some stuff..
    }
```

So is it possible to get a integer list to an action method from     window.locatipon.href,    and how..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `@Url.Action` is a razor template directive which will *not* execute on the client side, but instead before the page is returned by the server. So, no client-side code can affect it in any way. You'll have to construct the URL in JS, not with Razor.

Comment: It should not be marked as duplicate. The person who mark it duplicate make a blunder. The referenced question is not relevant to this question. it is about window.location.href.